# set NODE_PATH in netlify dev - absolute imports

Tags: environment-variables, netlify, netlify-function

Hi how can I set NODE_PATH like in .env file for a netlify dev. Because I got an errors

```
Module not found: Can't resolve 'index.css' in '/mnt/y/projects/instagram-story-saver/src'
```

App is built on Create React App

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.env file does not work, but newer method does work:

in jsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "src"
  },
  "include": ["src"]
}
```